# JLabel ImageIcon: stop auto centering in the frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, layout-manager

I have this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class test extends Canvas{

public static JFrame frame;
public static int WIDTH = 800;
public static int HEIGHT = 600;
public static BufferedImage img;
public static int[] pixels;
public static boolean running=true;

public static void main(String[] a){

        img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        frame = new JFrame("WINDOWw");
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}
```

How can I stop that black image from auto centering on the frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be the only component, it fills the frame.  Use text alignment or a `FlowLayout` if it is the only component.

[image: TestLabelPlacement - FlowLayout]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class TestLabelPlacement {

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static int WIDTH = 200;
    public static int HEIGHT = 150;
    public static BufferedImage img;

    public static void main(String[] a){

        img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        frame = new JFrame("Window");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // WRONG!  That is the size of the image, not the frame!
        //frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly ,but the image is not at exactly 0px x and 0px y

Comment: `frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING,0,0));`

Comment: One last question: Where did you learned this java programming because I saw you on many posts with good answers.

Comment: I learned Java **partly** from books, reading the Java Tutorials and a short course at college, **mostly** with a lot of looking at the Java Docs and posting to forums (you learn very quickly when you post a BAD answer ;) ).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13217/discussion-between-boyd-and-andrew-thompson)

Comment: I don't know how to say it but you have about half an hour free? I want to help me to start something .Actually I started it but it has lots of bugs

Comment: Ask a new question (or questions).

Answer (score 2):

JFrame will have **BorderLayout as the default layout**, and When there is **only one component** to be added to the frame, it **by default goes to the Center of the frame**.

You can use **GroupLayout**, and place the component to your desired locations. GroupLayout was developed by NetBean development team in 2005, its available in **Window Builder Pro, a GUI Building too, now freely available from Google.**